# Reading JSON file with filter

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a JSON file which has about 200000 rows. Each row is enclosed within `{}` and and its own structure.
When I use `df = spark.read.option("multiLine", "false").json(file_paths)`
I could read all and when I infer schema it gives me the entire structure.
When I filter for a certain `event_name` it filters data, but the structure is still of entire structure.
`filtered_df = df.filter(col("event.event_name").cast("string") == "XYZ")`

When I manually check the file it filtered event has only 20 columns but the entire structure has 100 columns. But my filtered_dy also show 100 columns.

I want to filter the structure as well.

Could someone help me with it?

Comment: Can you show the sample data along with the expected data?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.